# NX module federation with angular throws blocked by CORS policy when configuration is production

Tags: angular, cors, angular-module-federation

So, I created an example site for module-federation with NX, it has a HOST page and 6 REMOTE pages, ***it is not using backend for the time being***. All good working ok when running in NG SERVE mode, but now I tried to test this by deploying the apps into my LOCAL IIS and I get several CORS errors.

I believe I configured IIS properly, by adding the apps (one by one host and remotes) and also configuring the security to allow IIS user, after that, when I try to navigate I get this error:

- port: 6001 is my host.
- port: 6002 to 6007 are the remote pages.

[image]

Googling around, I found that I might need to configure the file `module-federation.config.js` to include headers, this is what I did, first in host only, then I added the same to all the remote apps.

```
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }
```

But the error still persists, so the question, **how to properly configure an NX Module federation site with HOST and REMOTES, to avoid the CORS exception?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue after understanding a bit more about IIS.

There is a section in IIS where you can specify the headers at server level, just added the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" and it started to work.